# Runnable Jar cannot find Resources and Other Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, executable-jar

I created a desktop app and I have run into a problem with my generated runnable jar. Everything works fine in the Eclipse environment, but when I generate the jar it only shows the`swt`components (menu, tabs, etc..).
The other libraries location is a blank area (library to generate gallery). The same does not appear`set ToolBar`(containing buttons with images),`GoogleMap.html`does not appear.

How can I correctly generate an executable jar that will include these external sources?

ToolBar image loading code :

```
folderSearchIcon = new Image(display, this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/search_folder.png"));
```

GoogleMap.html loading code :

```
File mapFile = new File("resources/GoogleMap.html");        
if(!mapFile.exists()) {
    System.out.println("File doesn't exist! " + mapFile.getAbsolutePath()); 
    return;
}
```

Generating runnable jar:

[image]

My app structure in Eclipse and generated jar structure:

[image]

Generated manifest :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ swt.jar commons-imaging-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.eclip
  se.nebula.widgets.gallery_0.5.3.201210262156.jar xmpcore.jar metadata
  -extractor-2.6.3.jar
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: geotagger.AppInit
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in the background when you run your app through the runnable jar?

Comment: Did you make sure that the resources are really contained in the jar? Just open it with an archiving software and check.

Comment: so `lib` folder is not included in the jar right? Just add them to Build Path using Eclipse

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov As you can see from the manifest and the second screenshot, the libraries **are** referenced in the jar.

Comment: On screen I showed unpacked jar content, I add `lib` folder to Eclipse project folder and next I choose `Build Path -> Add to Build Path` for each library

Comment: @unixhead According to your screenshot, your jar doesn't contain a `resources` folder, but you use it to access the `.html` file.

Comment: Why is he having libraries inside `lib` folder and outside in Eclipse?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Because that's the way Eclipse exports them...

Comment: @Baz, not in my case. Maybe mine is configured to hide those outside.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Does your jar contain a lib folder or is the lib folder created outside the jar?

Comment: @Baz, jar contains lib folder, I mean hiding in Package Explorer.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov Then maybe you chose a different setting for "Library handling".

Comment: @unixhead Have you tried using: `YourClass.class.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("images/search_folder.png");` instead?

Comment: The answer which works is provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/14105224/3488929
by @Reimeus

Comment: @DarshanShah Thanks :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the toolbar image you need to add a slash, i.e. instead of

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/search_folder.png")
```

you need

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/search_folder.png")
```

This is because, [as explained in the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), `Class.getResourceAsStream` resolves relative paths against the package of the class in question, so if `this` is a `com.example.Foo` then `getResourceAsStream("images/search_folder.png")` would look for `com/example/images/search_folder.png` inside your JAR.  Prepending the slash would make it look for `images/search_folder.png` instead, which is what your screenshot suggests you need.

You will need to use a similar trick for the `GoogleMap.html` - you can't load items from inside a JAR using `java.io.File`, but you could use `this.getClass().getResource("/GoogleMap.html")` to get a `java.net.URL` pointing to the HTML file inside your JAR.

Comment: Thanks it works! Runnable jar shows entire contents of the app but `GoogleMap.html` doesn't load in SWT Browser (in Eclipse works) but Browser has connection with network, `GoogleMap.html` loading code : `try { URL mapFile = getClass().getResource("/GoogleMap.html"); browserMap = new Browser(compositeTabItemMap, SWT.NONE); browserMap.setUrl(mapFile.toString()); } catch(NullPointerException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`

Comment: @unixhead In that case you may have to load the HTML into a string yourself and use `setText` instead of `setUrl`.  The SWT `Browser` is a wrapper around a native browser and may not be able to load Java-specific URL schemes.

Comment: So there is no other way to execute `*.html` file in jar ? It is much easier and more clearly :(

Comment: I tried this: 
`InputStream getHtml = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/GoogleMaps.html");
   Scanner htmlScanner = new Scanner(getHtml);
   StringBuffer htmlBuffer = new StringBuffer();
   
   while(htmlScanner.hasNextLine())
   {    htmlBuffer.append(htmlScanner.nextLine());   
   }   
   browserMap = new Browser(compositeTabItemMap, SWT.NONE);   
   browserMap.setText(htmlBuffer.toString());`
but google maps dosen't load in Eclipse .. I created simply html file and did the same .. Tn that case it works in Eclipse but in runnable jar still the same situtation as with GoogleMap.html

Comment: simply solution :) : 
java can't load html file from jar file because it must be decompressed to temp file in file sys. location, so I changed `.html` to `.txt` also I added `\n` in `append` method to correctly validate javascript code and it works very nice

Answer (score 3):

As you can see here:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

getResourceAsStream() looks for the file in the same package as the class from which it is called. Thus it will look for a file named "com/whatever/more/images/search_folder.png" inside the JAR, which of course won't exist, because the contents of the "resources" directory are directly put in the root of the JAR file by the JAR exporter.

Use [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

The second part: when you load the HTML will never work. You try to find a File named "resources/GoogleMap.html", but that will look outside of the JAR, in the working directory of your java program process. You should again use the previous function to load the HTML:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: So I ended up trying this after seeing the above solution that seems to work fine for me. Not sure why this has to be so obscure for Runnable Jars.  I placed the resource in my resources directory which I had added as part of the class path for Eclipse  
  
`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");`

Answer (score 3):

I lost many hours on this same issue. If you created your runnable jar using the options in the "Export" functionality in Eclipse, it just won't work.  At least it didn't for me.   No matter what number of options I tried, nothing worked. When trying to read the resources, the resourceUrl would return null.  Finally, I decided to create the runnable jar using Maven, and leave the Eclipse kind help aside.   I needed to have the dependent jars in a separate lib folder.   I created the runnable jar as explained in http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-manifest-file-with-maven/ and the solution worked for me.   Somehow, when Eclipse creates the runnable jar package, the resources cannot be read, even though they are present in the jar file.  Hope this will help others.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either. However, I did notice that copying the resources folder in the same folder of the runnable jar worked... Maybe this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Since exporting into a runnable jar essentially creates one file, the file/image/resource in your resources folder can no longer be found with FileReader because the file location is now non-existent..

Changing from using `FileReader fr = new FileReader(resource_file_path)` to loading with an InputStream, `InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource_file_path)` and then using an `InputStreamReader` to actually use the resource in other locations. Hope this helps.