# getResources() for ImageIcon - java

Tags: java, imageicon

my very first question:

I've been trying to figure this out for a couple of days, but I got to the point I lost my patience.
The following are some code and my project structure.

**QUESTION:** how can I get `getResources()` to work in eclipse and after being imported to jar?

Thanks for the help.

```
public enum Icons {
    XXX("src/resoruces/icons/xyz.png");
    private ImageIcon icon;
    Icons(String path) {
       try {
           // will fail miserably in eclipse and after exporting to jar
           URL imageURL = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path);
           icon = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // works like a char in eclipse and after creating the jar file
           // with the files in the same directory
           System.out.println("getResoruce() did not work");
           icon = new ImageIcon(path);
       }
   }
```

[image: Project Structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the png files have been packaged into the JAR in the same locations as they are in the original src directory then

```
XXX("resources/icons/xyz.png");
```

should produce the right result.

Answer (score 11):

Normally when exporting a JAR file from Eclipse, the contents of `src/resources` are exported *minus* the `src` path name itself. To get the image to load from your JAR you could do:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/icons/xyz.png");
ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(stream));
```

One way to know for sure is to check:

```
jar tvf yourjar.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

`src` directory is not available in classpath

```
InputStream imageInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/icons/xyz.png");
byte[] imageData = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(in)

ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(imageData, "description about image");
```