# eclipse build path not including top folders

Tags: eclipse, executable-jar, buildpath

I have my eclipse project setup as follows.  As you can see I have 'gamedata', 'images', and 'sounds' folders set  in my buildpath as libraries.

***Here is the folder structure of my project.***

[image: Package Explorer Filesystem setup]

I have been work on this client server game for quite some time now in eclipse and all is well.  I wanted to try to 'export' this as an 'executable jar' file.  I did that and when I went to run it, I got an error loading an image.  I then extracted the  contents of that jar file to see why it was missing and realized that the 'gamedata', 'images', and 'sounds' folders are all not there, rather their subfolders/contents are at the top level.

***This is the extracted folder below where you can see the missing top level folders.***

[image: Executable Jar extracted contents]

Can anyone help me out here?  Sorry if this is a stupid question but I have tried so many things in the build path and admittedly do not have much familiarity with it.  I have tried to look online for proper project setups(I remember using a res folder in programming classes way back) and would appreciate any guidance on best practices as far as folder naming is concerned.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Can anyone help out on this?  I still cant find a solution or see what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `images` and `gamedata` under a "`resources`" folder, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13989785/6309)

[image: resources]

Right-click your project, `new`, `Resource Folder`.
Add the path you want (`images` and `gamedata`).

Then select the option "**`Export Java source files and resources`**" when creating your jar executable.

Comment: but then when i look for the files in my project wont they not be found?  For example: redN = getToolkit().createCustomCursor(SpriteStore.get().getSprite("images/gui/gui_cursor_red_n_trans.png").getImage(), new Point(15, 9), "redN");  Will it find that under the resources folder?

Comment: @JayAvon I believe they will be found, but I guess you will be testing that soon.

Comment: does not work.  While the top level folders are now there in the bin folder I am having issues accessing them still... I think I need to change the way I find them now.  Will keep trying and get back to you

Comment: I am figuring this out...  either way I gave you my bounty as you got me on the right track... thanks for the help

Comment: @JayAvon Ok, but don't hesitate to post a more comprehensive solution there.

Comment: This worked after I tweaked some things.  Here's to hoping when I start to testing installs with my auto updating code that it works :)